# Convert float to varchar and preserve preceding zero in Excel import

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2012

I have an excel file with a column type 'Custom' = '0000000000000'

Here's the screenshot:
[image]

When importing the excel file through sql import export wizard the source column type is double. I want to preserve the preceding 0's, so I tried the destination type as varchar(max) but it's giving error: unable to convert.

Here's the error:
[image]

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want preceding zeroes, it's not really numeric (`Double`).

Import and store the field as text (`Varchar` or `Varchar(13)`).

In order to do so, you'll probably have to store the value as `Text` in Excel.

Comment: How I did: Copied all the data in the column leaving the column name. Pasted in notepad. Created new column in excel with type text. Pasted the data from notepad in new column. Then imported excel. It worked.